# encrypt message with AES-CBC with PKCS#7 padding using forge.js

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, forge

I need to apply `PKCS#7` padding to data which is being digested with AES-CBC algorithm. I use `forge` lib. Here's my currently working code (without the padding):

```
// transform json data to bytes
var data = {foo: 'bar'};
var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
var bytes = forge.util.createBuffer(stringData);

// generate 16-byte vector iv
var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);

// ciphering process
var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC', key);
cipher.start({iv: iv});
cipher.update(bytes);
cipher.finish();
var encrypted = cipher.output;
```

So from the theoretical point of view I know that I should append 1-16 bytes to my `bytes` variable before passing it to `aes` algorithm. Is this kind of operation built into the `forge` lib?  If not, could someone help me with implementing application of padding to the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought the documentation does not mention it, seems the default padding for AES-CBC is PKCS#7. See [this thread](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/130) and the comments of [cipherModes.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/js/cipherModes.js)

```
modes.cbc.prototype.pad = function(input, options) {
  // add PKCS#7 padding to block (each pad byte is the
  // value of the number of pad bytes)
```